# Can I send multiple image URLs to BlueMix Visual Recognition service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

Can I send multiple image URLs to BlueMix Visual Recognition service?
I know I can zip up a set of images and send in one call, but it doesn't look like I can provide a list of URLs?

https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/visual-recognition-v3#!/visual-recognition/get_v3_classify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no: batch URL input is not supported, but it's good to know this is of interest. There are many quirks about crawling multiple URLs that we would need to consider before rolling out this feature, but it's not impossible.

I'll make sure to surface this request, and thanks for your usage of the Visual Recognition service!